# Making a OOP forum

Tags: php, oop, forum

I've learned the basics of OOP and though I should attempt to make something simple, (just to learn and because I'm bored). The problem is I'm having trouble deciding what classes I'm going to need. Database abstraction and (user input) validation pretty much sort themselves out. It'll be in PHP, but I think all forums designed in OOP share a common set of classes.

The forum will be very simple, register, login, view, post and reply.
I was thinking something along the lines of the list below:

- Registration class
- User class: class to manage users
- User_Post class: class to manage user posts
- Posts class: manage posts
- Validation class (PHP filters?)

To me Hierarchical threading seems incredibly complex to program for a noob like me.
A really simple forum I like is the [BBCs 606](http://www.bbc.co.uk/dna/606/ArticleSearch?contenttype=-1&phrase=Arsenal&phrase=Football) forum.

Maybe openID for validation?

Thats all I got so far.

Comment: He wants to know which classes he needs to build a simple forum and if he should use openID. A bit broad, but those are his questions.

Comment: @webbie: A *bit* broad? He wants someone to design and spec his project for him...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you "think all forums designed in OOP share a common set of classes", why not do some surgery on existing software? (There is a load of open source forum-software out there.)
That way you'll learn about the common set of classes, how they work, interact and the overall process of building a larger piece of software.

My guess is that equipped with that knowledge you'll be far better of building your own forum than with any answer (or rather: opinion) about what classes you *should* use or need.

Comment: +1 Good point.. some of these forums are so bloated though, I don't know where to start.

Comment: Even bloated software has little granular classes and methods. Or: Work your way up :) ... start with something smaller. Try a guestbook first, do a blog afterwards, then go for the forum. After that aim higher: portal, community ... the sky's the limit :)

Comment: Lol, I just realised I can't voteup

Comment: I was already wondering where that point went :)

Answer (score 0):

For the login I would´nt recommend openID I thik you would be more "part of the process" if you srt with something like [this](http://www.evolt.org/node/60384).

It is simple enough and will be more in line with a **PHP** forum in my opinion.

I would also take a look some reference is some good "simple" php forums out there like [PunBB](http://punbb.informer.com/)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you abstract properly, you will realize the benefits of OO and Active Record. Then you will be able to walk upon the rice paper without making a sound.

Design tables, then build one class per table.  Be strict with noun(s) and verb(s).

ex:

```
 users
     id
     username
     password
     
  forums
     id
     name
     
   posts
      id
      user_id
      body

   forum_posts
       id
       forum_id
       post_id
```

There are 3 classes here:

- User
- Post
- Forum

By using static methods in the appropriate class, you can build this intelligently:

```
    $user->forum_posts('id DESC'); 
# function forum_posts($order_by) { return Forum::get_for_user($this->id, $order_by); }
    
    $user->forum_post($forum_id, array('body' => 'Foo')); 
# function forum_post($forum_id, $array) { return Forum::post_to($forum_id, $this->id, $array); }
```

continue like this. think about very small pieces and every thing will come together.  Give every class a list of fields, __call, get(), set(), and factory methods to get related classes

## tl;dr abstract and design tables, write overloaded classes with short factory methods for selects and inserts.